# apt cacher wont do-release-upgrade for saucy

Tags: 13.04, 13.10, apt, do-release-upgrade, apt-cacher

My sys (raring) is proxy client of my another machine hosting apt cacher. I'm trying to do-release-upgrage and console saying `403, Sorry, not allowed to fetch that type of file: saucy.tar.gz` and the command fails. (Im sure I can get out of this issue if I remove the proxy setting in my apt.conf.d but I really need to cache everything too.)

Answer (score 3):

The version of `apt-cacher` running on the proxy host is out of date.

See https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=600893 and https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt-cacher/+bug/561902.

In my case I found that because I had modified `/etc/apt-cacher/apt-cacher.conf` on my proxy host, regular apt[itude] upgrades had not updated `apt-cacher.conf`.

I found `apt-cacher.conf.dpkg-dist` in the same directory, used diff to determine which settings I needed to keep, then updated `apt-cacher.conf`.

Since I'm updating to Trusty, I also added it to the "ubuntu_release_names" list in the same file, restarted `apt-cacher` and all is well.

(My proxy is running 12.10)